# Python Pandas code takes over a minute to process the data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two issues with the below code:

(a) It takes over a minutes to process a record
(b) I receive a Warning [A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame. See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy]

```
for stock in stocklist:
    ...
    ...
    df['Up Move'] = np.nan
    df['Down Move'] = np.nan
    df['Average Up'] = np.nan
    df['Average Down'] = np.nan
    df['RS'] = np.nan
    df['RSI'] = np.nan

    for x in range(1, len(df)):
        df['Up Move'][x] = 0
        df['Down Move'][x] = 0
        if df['Close'][x] > df['Close'][x-1]:
            df['Up Move'][x] = df['Close'][x] - df['Close'][x-1]

        if df['Close'][x] < df['Close'][x-1]:
            df['Down Move'][x] = abs(df['Close'][x] - df['Close'][x-1])

    #Calculate initial Average Up & Down, RS and RSI
    df['Average Up'][14] = df['Up Move'][1:15].mean()
    df['Average Down'][14] = df['Down Move'][1:15].mean()
    df['RS'][14] = df['Average Up'][14] / df['Average Down'][14]
    df['RSI'][14] = 100 - (100/(1+df['RS'][14]))

    #Calculate rest of Average Up, Average Down, RS, RSI
    for x in range(15, len(df)):
        df['Average Up'][x] = (df['Average Up'][x-1]*13+df['Up Move'][x])/14
        df['Average Down'][x] = (df['Average Down'][x-1]*13+df['Down Move'][x])/14
        df['RS'][x] = df['Average Up'][x] / df['Average Down'][x]
        df['RSI'][x] = 100 - (100/(1+df['RS'][x]))

    df.drop(['Up Move', 'Down Move', 'Average Up', 'Average Down'], axis = 1, inplace = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid using `for loop` to handle dataframe.

the code:

```
    #Calculate rest of Average Up, Average Down, RS, RSI
    for x in range(15, len(df)):
        df['Average Up'][x] = (df['Average Up'][x-1]*13+df['Up Move'][x])/14
        df['Average Down'][x] = (df['Average Down'][x-1]*13+df['Down Move'][x])/14
        df['RS'][x] = df['Average Up'][x] / df['Average Down'][x]
        df['RSI'][x] = 100 - (100/(1+df['RS'][x]))
```

may equal to:

```
    df.loc[15:, 'Average Up'] = df.loc[15:, 'Average Up'].shift(-1)*13 + df.loc[15:, 'Up Move'][x]/14
    df.loc[15:, 'Average Down'] = df.loc[15:, 'Average Down'].shift(-1)*13 + df.loc[15:, 'Up Down'][x]/14
    
    df.loc[15:, 'RS'] = df.loc[15:, 'Average Up']/ df.loc[15:, 'Average Down']
    df.loc[15:, 'RSI'] = 100 - (100/(1+df.loc[15:, 'RS'][x]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just found the code that gives me the same right result in a couple of seconds. The earlier code would take about one minute to three minutes.

```
# Compute RSI
def computeRSI (data, time_window):
    diff = data.diff(1).dropna()        # diff in one field(one day)

    #this preservers dimensions off diff values
    up_chg = 0 * diff
    down_chg = 0 * diff

    # up change is equal to the positive difference, otherwise equal to zero
    up_chg[diff > 0] = diff[ diff>0 ]

    # down change is equal to negative deifference, otherwise equal to zero
    down_chg[diff < 0] = diff[ diff < 0 ]

    # check pandas documentation for ewm
    # https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ewm.html
    # values are related to exponential decay
    # we set com=time_window-1 so we get decay alpha=1/time_window
    up_chg_avg   = up_chg.ewm(com=time_window-1 , min_periods=time_window).mean()
    down_chg_avg = down_chg.ewm(com=time_window-1 , min_periods=time_window).mean()

    rs = abs(up_chg_avg/down_chg_avg)
    rsi = 100 - 100/(1+rs)
    return rsi

# Calculate the RSI values using our function and add them to the dataframe.
df['RSI'] = computeRSI(df['Adj Close'], 14)

print(df.head())
print(df.tail())
```